# How to cast Wildcard (?) to a Generic type T?

Tags: java, generics, casting, wildcard

I have a static method that i want to use to load classes and instantiate my objects at runtime, but when i compile, i got this warning:

```
warning: [unchecked] unchecked cast
            T t = (T) ctor.newInstance();
required: T
found:    CAP#1
where T is a type-variable:
    T extends Object declared in method <T>forName(String,Set<String>)
    where CAP#1 is a fresh type-variable:
    CAP#1 extends Object from capture of ?
1 warning
```

Here's the code:

```
public static <T> Set<T> forName(String modulePath, Set<String> classes) throws InvalidModuleException{
    try {
        ClassLoader cl = new URLClassLoader(new URL[]{new URL(modulePath)});

        Set<T> list = new HashSet<>(classes.size());
        for (String className : classes) {
            Class<?> clazz = (Class<?>) Class.forName(className, true, cl);
            Constructor<?> ctor = clazz.getConstructor();
            T t = (T) ctor.newInstance();
            list.add(t);
        }
        return list;    
    } catch (MalformedURLException | ReflectiveOperationException ex) {
        throw new InvalidModuleException(ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Someone can explain me that?

[UPDATE]
Here's and example of method call:

```
HashSet<String> set = new HashSet<>();
h.add("fully_classfied_classname_readed_from_file"); //Class that extends AbstractApplication
Set<AbstractApplication> abs = Apps.forName("plugins/module.jar", set);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is one missing bit. First, you try to typecast every object to `T`. If you know `T` prehand, I do not see a reason on who you need to pass a set of strings when a class object would do

Suppose if you still need to in case of possibility of sub-classes:

```
public static <T> Set<? extends T> forName(String modulePath, Set<String> classes, Class<T> claz) throws InvalidModuleException{
    try {
    ClassLoader cl = new URLClassLoader(new URL[]{new URL(modulePath)});

    Set<T> list = new HashSet<>(classes.size());
    for (String className : classes) {
        Class<?> clazz = Class.forName(className, true, cl);
        Constructor<?> ctor = clazz.getConstructor();
        Object obj = ctor.newInstance();
        list.add(claz.cast(obj));
    }
    return list;
} catch (MalformedURLException | ReflectiveOperationException | ClassCastException ex) {
    throw new InvalidModuleException(ex.getMessage());
}
}
```

Comment: That is what i want. Load subclasses (See the update). I guess your code can help.

Comment: Alternately, you can change the type on the class beforehand `Class<? extends T> clazz = Class.forName(...).asSubclass(claz);`

Answer (score 3):

You cannot do that in a safe way using strings to indicate the classes. For one thing, there is no way for the compiler to know that the set of strings actually contains fully-qualified class names; even if they are class names, there is no guarantee that the classes specified by the names are subclasses of `T`.

Instead of passing in a set of strings, pass in a set of classes, constrained to be subclasses of `T`:

```
Set<Class<? extends T>> classes
```

Then you can just iterate over these classes, and remove the need for any casting:

```
for (Class<? extends T> clazz : classes) {
  Constructor<? extends T> ctor = clazz.getConstructor();
  T t = ctor.newInstance();
  list.add(t);
}
```

If the requirement to defer initializations of the classes is absolute, you have little choice but to add `@SuppressWarnings` appropriately to this method, and hope that the configuration from which these strings are loaded is correct.

Comment: I use a Set<String> because the classes names was readed from a file.
I save in a file the classes that i will use.

Comment: @ehbarbian please refer to the last sentence then. You are doing something inherently unsafe from a type perspective.